# Why can't I access the delegate property of my view controller in my Swift project?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a view controller called `ServiceDetailController` with a delegate property shown below:

```
weak var delegate: ServiceDetailControllerDelegate?
```

and I am trying to initialize it with a delegate instance in the next view controller in the navigation stack using:

```
for controller in navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
    if controller.isKind(of: ServiceDetailController.self) {
        controller.delegate = self
    }
}
```

But Xcode is giving me an error

> Value of type 'UIViewController" has no member 'delegate'.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code confirms that a controller is of type `ServiceDetailController` before it runs the code after your if statement, but inside the if statement, the variable `controller` is still of type ViewController. (Actually, since you cast `navigationController!.viewControllers` to `Array`, `controller` is probably type `Any`. I'd get rid of that `as Array` bit from your for loop. It does more harm than good.)

You need to cast the variable to the right type in order to access properties of your specific subclass. Change your code as follows:

```
    for controller in navigationController!.viewControllers {
        if let sdc = controller as? ServiceDetailController {
            sdc.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

The `if let` syntax is called "optional binding", and creates a new variable inside the braces of the if statement that is valid if the `if let` succeeds. In our case we're using `as?` to try to cast the view controller to type `ServiceDetailController`. If the cast succeeds, the code inside the braces is executed, and has access to the variable `sdc`,which is of type `ServiceDetailController`.